# error in execution policy using powershell version 1.0

Tags: powershell

Iam using following command for silent installation of service pack on servers

```
 H:\>powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -nologo -file path\SP_Ins
tallation.ps1   ax-riscvmsql68\sql68  d:\sysdba\SQLServer2008SP4-KB2979596-x64-E
NU.exe 2>&1
```

iam not getting any error while running this command on powershell version4.0

when iam running same command on version 1.0 it gives me following error

```
H:\>powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -nologo -file path\SP_Installation.ps1   ax-riscvmsql68\sql68  d:\sysdba\SQLServer2008SP4-KB2979596-x64-ENU.exe 2>&1
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At line:1 char:2
+ -e <<<< xecutionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -nologo -file path\SP_Installation.ps1 ax-riscvmsql68\sql68 d:\sysdba\SQLServer2008SP4-KB2979596-x64-ENU.exe
```

can you please help me out as execution policy is not recognized in powershell version 1.0

Comment: Move away from PowerShell v1. Now. All currently supported systems can run at least PowerShell v3. Even the more recent out-of-support systems like XP can run at least PowerShell v2.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.activexperts.com/admin/powershell/powershell10/set-executionpolicy/)

You can only use `restricted`, `remotesigned`, `Allsigned`, and `unrestricted` in Powershell v1.0.

- **Restricted**

  Do not load configuration files or run scripts.
     This is the default.
- **AllSigned**

  Require that all scripts and configuration files be signed
     by a trusted publisher, including scripts that you write on the loca
      l computer.
- **RemoteSigned**

  Require that all scripts and configuration files downloaded
     from the Internet be signed by a trusted publisher.
- **Unrestricted**

  Load all configuration files and run all scripts.
     If you run an unsigned script that was downloaded from the
     internet, you are prompted for permission before it runs.

As @Ansgar Wiechers said please move away from v1.0... It is extremely outdated and most systems use v3.0 and above. Some commands and properties are not available in v1.0 than other updated versions.

Answer (score 0):

so here is solution you cannot user powershell version 1.0 for execution policy host needs to be on powershell version 2.0 +